# JS filter function multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter, vuejs2

This might be a duplicate but I cant seem to find a stackoverflow question with my exact question. I'm displaying a table of data in the frontend and i'm allowing the user to filter by multiple optional variables. So lets say my data variables are user details in this format:

```
[
    {
        firstName = 'bob', 
        middleName = 'bruh', 
        lastName = 'bub'
    },
     .
     .
     .
    {
        firstName = 'sam', 
        middleName = 'marley', 
        lastName = 'jackson'
    }
]
```

Now im allowing the users to filter by firstName, middleName and LastName. But they are also allowed to filter using only one variable, or a combination of any of the three.

The naive approach that I am using now is to have 7 if statements that filter the array depending on the user input:

so

```
let filterByFirstName = this.firstNameQuery !== null;
let filterByMiddleName = this.middleNameQuery !== null;
let filterByLastName = this.lastNameQuery !== null;

if(filterByFirstName && !filterByMiddleName && !filterByLastName)
//filter the array only by first name 

else if(filterByFirstName && filterByMiddleName && !filterByLastName)
// filter array by first and middle name 

.
.
.

else if(filterByFirstName && filterByMiddleName && filterByLastName) 
//filter array by first, middle and last name.
```

So algorithmically its efficient enough, but not so much for the cleanliness of the code as i will be adding more and more variable to filter by.

I have tried creating just one filter statement that will filter depending on the variables supplied but i'm having trouble coding it.

```
let filterByFirstName = this.firstNameQuery !== null;
let filterByMiddleName = this.middleNameQuery !== null;
let filterByLastName = this.lastNameQuery !== null;

  this.displayArray = this.userArray.filter(
    user =>
      user.firstName === (filterByFirstName ? this.firstNameQuery : 'any String') &&
      user.middleName === (filterByMiddleName ? this.middleNameQuery : 'any String') &&
      user.lastName === (filterByLastName ? this.lastNameQuery : 'any String')
  );
```

So essentially what i need is a wildcard or the equivalent of any string to put in the filter function, if this is even possible. Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Your input's syntax is invalid. And what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: whoops, i didnt meant to add java. This is a simplified version of my code, i dont wanna copy paste the whole thing as it can be harder to understand. the code runs fine its just i need a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```js
let filters = {firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Foo', lastName: null}
let data = [{firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Doe'}]

console.log(data.filter((item) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filters)) {
    if (value) return item[key] === value
  }
}))
```